# Best way to take an array of items and if they match set a variable

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am making a db call and grabbing all services for an order. If there are specific services associated with an order I need to set a variable. This is how I am doing it currently and it will not work because once I set a variable the next item comes around and squashes it. It overwrites the correct value from the service item before it.

```
$services = OrderService::where('order_id','=',$payload['orderId'])->get(['service_id']);
foreach($services as $service){
    //Screen
    if($service->service_id == 4){ $responseArray['lnpScreen'] = '1';}
    else{ $responseArray['lnpScreen'] = '0'; }
    //Screen 2
    if($service->service_id == 5){ $responseArray['tfpScreen'] = '1';}
    else{ $responseArray['tfpScreen'] = '0'; }
    //Screen 3
    if($service->service_id == 6){ $responseArray['didScreen'] = '1';}
    else{ $responseArray['didScreen'] = '0'; }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to use a `switch` statement instead of `if/else`.

Comment: @powtac If I use a switch statement what would be the best way to set them to 0? Set that as the default before this is set?

Comment: @ipengineer see my answer to see how to use the `switch` in your example

Comment: @ipengineer if that solved your problem please accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here that should work:

```
$responseArray['lnpScreen'] = '0';
$responseArray['tfpScreen'] = '0';
$responseArray['didScreen'] = '0';
foreach($services as $service){
    //Screen
    if($service->service_id == 4){ $responseArray['lnpScreen'] = '1';}
    //Screen 2
    if($service->service_id == 5){ $responseArray['tfpScreen'] = '1';}
    //Screen 3
    if($service->service_id == 6){ $responseArray['didScreen'] = '1';}
}
```

now they won't overwrite eachother anymore.

or as powtac mentioned:

```
$responseArray['lnpScreen'] = '0';
$responseArray['tfpScreen'] = '0';
$responseArray['didScreen'] = '0';
foreach($services as $service){
    switch($service->service_id){
        case 4://Screen
          $responseArray['lnpScreen'] = '1';
          break;
        case 5://Screen 2
          $responseArray['tfpScreen'] = '1';
          break;
        case 6://Screen 3
          $responseArray['didScreen'] = '1';
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: They will still overwrite.  On the third looping of the foreach, the second service will be overwritten.  He needs a multidimensional array.

Comment: What? how will the services be abple to write a 0?

Comment: @Steve The 0's are set before the foreach. and in the foreach the only thing that might be done is setting a 1. how will they be overwritten? In the OP question the foreach put a 0 into the responsearray for each service because of the else part!

Comment: It's not about writing a "0"... It's about looping over multiple services (let's say 5 services).  In the first looping, you might set  `$responseArray['lnpScreen'] = '1';`, but what if in the second service `$service->service_id` is NOT 4?

Comment: @Steve so? then it isn't and absolutely nothing happens! I still don't see your problem

Comment: Well, let me clarify... I agree with your setting of the '0's before the switch.  My argument is that there are multiple services.  Let's assume `$services[0]->service_id` is 4, `$services[1]->service_id` is 3 and `$services[2]->service_id` is 4.  The anser you suggest only keeps track of `$services[2]`. The OP probably wants to keep track of the status of each service.  Hence he needs a multidimensinal array.

Comment: @Steve you do realize that i do the zeroing before the `foreach` right?

Comment: I went ahead and used the switch method you provided. Worked perfectly thank you.

Comment: and also i think that the service id's are unique. Or at least they should be. Because otherwise it wouldn't be called an ID

Comment: @ITroubs - I do understand that... I am not arguing at your approach to zero before the foreach.  I very much like that approach. What I am saying is: The OP has many services. And I "assume" that he wants to keep track of the screen type for each service, not just the type for the last service.

Comment: @Steve as he doesn't get any kind of information  from the service other than the service_id which should be unique and by doing a comparison of such a unique id there only will be exactly one case where a service will have the id 4 thus `$responseArray['lnpScreen']=1` is sufficient.

Comment: @ITroubs - looking at the assumption you put forth in your last comment (which seems to be true according to the OP), you are right. :)

Comment: @Steve otherwise I would have agreed with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting because you use the same `$responseArray` every time you loop.  You need to use a multidimensional array to keep track of each service. Something like that might get you started:

```
$services = OrderService::where('order_id','=',$payload['orderId'])->get(['service_id']);
$count = 0;
foreach($services as $service){
    //Screen
    if($service->service_id == 4){ $responseArray[$count]['lnpScreen'] = '1';}
    else{ $responseArray[$count]['lnpScreen'] = '0'; }
    //Screen 2
    if($service->service_id == 5){ $responseArray[$count]['tfpScreen'] = '1';}
    else{ $responseArray[$count]['tfpScreen'] = '0'; }
    //Screen 3
    if($service->service_id == 6){ $responseArray[$count]['didScreen'] = '1';}
    else{ $responseArray[$count]['didScreen'] = '0'; }
    $count++;
}
```